# I can not use the properties and variables of a library of classes within a dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I have this problem, a compiled dll in VB, I need to use properties of this dll in C # but only loaded reference methods. this is driving me crazy, the properties are public, do not understand what happens, forgive my English. I'm new to this site sorry if I ask wrong

[i don't know how to show you the problem, here is a picture :S ][1]
http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/aaaa-836710.png?

Comment: Ok so VB dll, to be used in C#, right? So why is this tagged C++?

Comment: Do you know that C# is case-sensitive? You need to spell names like they are spelled in the original.

Comment: yes I know that, thanks for reply, but thats no the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i'm wrong, but if the properties are not marked as static (or not in a VB Module), then you need to create an instance of the class of your print screen:

```
libreriaCobol lc = new libreriaCobol();
lc.property = "";  // here.
```

This solves your problem?

Comment: WOW, I cant believe that I missed that, thank u so much men, :D